# Value of a polynomial at two points are equal

Tags: polynomials

If the value of a polynomial at two points are same then what can said about the points ?
Are they equal?

Comment: Not necessarily. At least they lie on the same horizontal line.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much nothing. For example, if a polynomial $f(x)$ is such that $f(a)=0, f(b)=0$ (i.e. $a,b$ are roots of $f(x)$) then $x-a$ divides $f(x)$ and $x-b$ divides $f(x)$.

But, you can put the roots pretty much anywhere if you want to construct a polynomial: you could ask for roots $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ for any (not necessarily distinct) values and get the polynomial $f(x) = K (x-a_1) \ldots (x-a_n)$ to have those roots.